# How to validate yaml using yq?

Tags: validation, yq

I know there are at least two `yq`, I'm using this one: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq. According to [the doc](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v3.x/commands/validate), I can validate a `yaml` file like this:

```
yq -v file.yaml
```

The problem: it outputs a lot of debug info however according to the doc, it should outputs "nothing if [the file] valid, otherwise it will print errors". As far as I see, the file looks valid.

How should I avoid output if the file is valid then?

The file:

```
name: Copywrite

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  copywrite:
    name: Run Header Copyright
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@93ea575cc8 # v3.1.0

      - name: Install Copywrite
        id: install
        uses: hashicorp/setup-copywrite@v1.0.0

      - name: Output Installed Copywrite Version
        run: echo "Installed Copywrite CLI ${{steps.install.outputs.version}}"

      - name: Run Copywrite Header Compliance
        run: copywrite headers --plan
```

The output:

```
yq -v ./file.yml
16:52:54 processArgs [DEBU] processed args: [./file.yml]
16:52:54 maybeFile [DEBU] checking './file.yml' is a file
16:52:54 maybeFile [DEBU] error: <nil>, dir: false
16:52:54 maybeFile [DEBU] result: true
16:52:54 FormatFromFilename [DEBU] checking file extension './file.yml' for auto format detection
16:52:54 FormatFromFilename [DEBU] detected format 'yml'
16:52:54 initCommand [DEBU] Using input format yml
16:52:54 initCommand [DEBU] Using output format yml
16:52:54 ParseExpression [DEBU] Parsing expression: []
16:52:54 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] postfix processing currentToken )
16:52:54 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] opstackLen: 0
16:52:54 ConvertToPostfix [DEBU] PostFix Result:
16:52:54 GetMatchingNodes [DEBU] getMatchingNodes - nothing to do
16:52:54 PrintResults [DEBU] PrintResults for 1 matches
16:52:54 PrintResults [DEBU] -- print sep logic: p.firstTimePrinting: false, previousDocIndex: 0, mappedDoc.Document: 0
16:52:54 PrintResults [DEBU] D0, P[], (doc)::name: Copywrite
on:
    push:
        tags:
            - v*
        branches:
            - main
    pull_request:
    workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
    copywrite:
        name: Run Header Copyright
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@93ea575cc8 # v3.1.0
            - name: Install Copywrite
              id: install
              uses: hashicorp/setup-copywrite@v1.0.0
            - name: Output Installed Copywrite Version
              run: echo "Installed Copywrite CLI ${{steps.install.outputs.version}}"
            - name: Run Copywrite Header Compliance
              run: copywrite headers --plan
name: Copywrite
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  copywrite:
    name: Run Header Copyright
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@93ea575cc8 # v3.1.0
      - name: Install Copywrite
        id: install
        uses: hashicorp/setup-copywrite@v1.0.0
      - name: Output Installed Copywrite Version
        run: echo "Installed Copywrite CLI ${{steps.install.outputs.version}}"
      - name: Run Copywrite Header Compliance
        run: copywrite headers --plan
16:52:54 PrintResults [DEBU] done printing results
```

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, the documentation uses `v` as command (no dash), you are trying to use it as flag `-v`. Secondly, you are referencing a documentation for version 3.x but your output suggests you are using version 4.x.

With version 3.x the following works, and gives no output if the file is valid:

```bash
yq v file.yaml
# or
yq validate file.yaml
```

With version 4.x (where `-v` and `--verbose` stand for verbose mode), you could simply feed the file into yq (defaulting to the idempotent filter `.`), and suppress stdout. Possible errors will come through on stderr.

```bash
yq file.yaml >/dev/null
```